# How to show error message from Servlet to jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

So I have servlet that creates task.
How do I make "Error" message from servlet to my JSP that show error text if task with this name already exists?

doPost looks like this:

```
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        String priority = request.getParameter("priority");
        Task task = new Task(title, Priority.valueOf(priority.toUpperCase()));
        if(taskRepository.create(task)){
            response.sendRedirect("/task-list");
        }else{
            response.sendRedirect("/create-task");
        }
```

[Picture with error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl2hG.png)
If its "ok" he show's me task list. But if its not, it has to show me the same create page, but with Error message, picture related. Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
Servlet:

```
if (taskRepository.create(task)) {
            response.sendRedirect("/task-list");
        } else {
            List<String> err = new ArrayList<>();
            err.add("Task with given name already exists!");
            request.setAttribute("err", err);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/create-task.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Jsp:

```
<span class="error">${err}</span>
```